# What is the formula for the beta coefficients in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients

I am doing a study about logistic regression. I have to write a program for the admission process of the school.  The result is passed or failed.

```
Logit = L = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + …+ bkXk ...
```

What is the formula for b0, b1, b2, b3 (i.e., the beta coefficients) that can be seen at the picture? What is the formula for the raw coefficient for logistic regression?

[image: finding the formula that outputs these variables]

Comment: The coefficients are the solutions of the maximum likelihood equations (see 2.1.2 of the link below), there is no closed form formula for them, they are computed via iterative procedures (e.g. see 2.1.3 of the link) http://czep.net/stat/mlelr.pdf

Comment: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30884/70282

Comment: A question asking about how the betas are calculated is not really a question asking for code. This should be considered on topic here, IMO.

Comment: The question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94 asks for characterizations of the (very special) cases where a formula might exist.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30884/70282, you'll notice you can divide or multiple by the std dev of the predictor variable to go back and forth.

**Example:**

```
d=data.frame(x1=runif(1000,10,20),
             x2=runif(1000,100,200),
             x3=runif(1000,0,100))
d$y=ifelse(d$x1>15 & d$x2>150 & d$x3>50,1,0)
summary(d)
d2=as.data.frame(scale(d))
d2$y=d$y
summary(m <- glm(y~.,d,family = 'binomial'))
summary(m2 <- glm(y~.,d2,family = 'binomial'))
coef(m) #metric coeff
coef(m2) #standarized coef
coef(m)*c(1,sd(d$x1),sd(d$x2),sd(d$x3)) #standardized from metric
coef(m2)/c(1,sd(d$x1),sd(d$x2),sd(d$x3)) #metric from standardized
```

As a function:

```
logistic.beta=function(m){
  coef(m)[-1]*sapply(m$data,sd)[names(coef(m))[-1]]
}
```

Comment: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235057/70282 for lin reg

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @fcop, there is no formula (analytical solution) for the $\beta$. Here is an example on how the coefficients are calculated using iterative methods. (Comparing to R `glm` function)

x=as.matrix(mtcars[,c("wt","hp")])
    y=mtcars$am

```
logistic_loss <- function(w){
  p=plogis(x %*% w)
  L=-y*log(p)-(1-y)*log(1-p)
  sum(L)
}

logistic_loss_gr <- function(w){
  p=plogis(x %*% w)
  v=t(x) %*% (p - y)
  c(v)
}

res=optim(c(0.1,0.1),fn=logistic_loss, gr = logistic_loss_gr ,method="BFGS")

res$p

glm(am~wt+hp-1,mtcars,family=binomial())$coefficients
```

[image]

The coeffcients are pretty close but not exact the same, see this post for explaination.

[R using GLM and manual solve logistic regression have different (close but not exactly the same) results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229720/r-using-glm-and-manual-solve-logistic-regression-have-different-close-but-not-e)